# Clear Cisco ASA connection count

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

Here's what I'm doing to get a connection count on my ASA

> asa# show conn count
>   100 in use, 3389 most used
>   asa#

I want to reset the most used count. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you are looking for is below:

```
cisco-asa# **clear resource usage resource conns**
```

See [this Cisco reference](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa81/command/ref/c3.html#wp2153022) for more details.